# Measuring skewness of abundance over time

Tags: time-series, count-data

I have measurements of flower counts thru time for a bunch of species and locations. I'm interested in whether they are more or less "normally" distributed, with a peak in the middle and symmetric, or skewed to the left or right in time. It seems like I would be able to do this with various skewness tests or fitting different distributions, but since these are not histograms but timeseries I feel like that would be incorrect.

Here is some example data of a skewed timeseries and one that is fairly symmetric.

```
skewed_counts = c(2,9,17,32,40,32,12,11,9,2,2,5,5,3,4,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1)
skewed_time = c(202,204,206,208,210,212,215,217,219,221,222,224,226,228,230,232,236,238,240,242,244,246,248,250)

symmetric_counts = c(1,8,8,26,42,48,66,52,63,20,18,27,6,3)
symmetric_time = c(188,190,192,194,196,198,200,202,204,206,208,210,212,214)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you *can* interpret your data as a histogram if you consider the time of each individual observation of a flower as a random variable. Time histograms are used all the time, for example, in neuroscience (See, e.g., ["A Method for Selecting the Bin Size of a Time Histogram"](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/neco.2007.19.6.1503)).

So it's fine to test for normality of your data (using any one of several tests), but it sounds like you are more interested in checking for symmetry and a small tail, properties that are not unique to the normal distribution. You can use [skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) and [kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) to do this.

You seem to be familiar with skewness, which measures symmetry. However, as you have intuited, low skewness is not a sufficient condition for the shape you are looking for because, e.g., the data in row 2, column 8 is symmetric but bimodal. You can use kurtosis to quantify this deviation from a central peak and compare it to the normal distribution, which has a kurtosis value of 3.

Here is some Matlab code to compute this for your example data:

```
skewTime = [202,204,206,208,210,212,215,217,219,221,222,224,226,228,230,232,236,238,240,242,244,246,248,250];
skewCount = [2,9,17,32,40,32,12,11,9,2,2,5,5,3,4,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1];
symCount = [1,8,8,26,42,48,66,52,63,20,18,27,6,3];
symTime = [188,190,192,194,196,198,200,202,204,206,208,210,212,214];

% Turn the data into sets of individual time-valued observations
Nskew = length(skewCount);
skewData = [];
for i = 1:Nskew
    skewData = [skewData repmat(skewTime(i),[1 skewCount(i)])];
end

Nsym = length(symCount);
symData = [];
for i = 1:Nsym
    symData = [symData repmat(symTime(i),[1 symCount(i)])];
end

% Calculate kurtosis
Kskew = kurtosis(skewData);
Ksym = kurtosis(symData);
Knorm = 3;
% Calculate skewness
Sskew = skewness(skewData);
Ssym = skewness(symData);
Snorm = 0;

c = categorical({'1. symmetric data','2. normal distr.','3. skewed data'});

figure
subplot(211)
bar(c,[Ssym,Snorm,Sskew]), title('Skewness')
subplot(212)
bar(c,[Ksym,Knorm,Kskew]), title('Kurtosis')
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet! I like it.